# How to save many-to-many data using form.instance?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am writing an application on `Django`.

How can I save data (`provider.category`) from `form` using `form.instance`.

**models**

```
class RequestProvider(models.Model):
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name="provider_request")
```

**forms**

```
class ProviderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = RequestProvider
        fields = ('category',)
        widgets = {
            'category': forms.SelectMultiple(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'select2',
                    'style': 'width: 246px;'
                }
            ),
        }
```

**views**

```
@method_decorator(currency_account_dec, name='dispatch')
class ProviderCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = ProviderForm
    template_name = 'provider_create.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        provider_id = self.kwargs.get('provider_id',None)
        session_user = self.request.user
        if provider_id:
            form.instance.provider = Provider.objects.get(pk=provider_id)
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        #form.instance.category = form.cleaned_data.get('category')
        return super(ProviderCreateView,self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        provider_id = self.kwargs.get('provider_id',None)
        ss = RequestProvider.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        for s in ss:
            print(s.category)
        ctx = super(ProviderCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['organizations'] = Organization.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        ctx['payments'] = Payment.objects.all()
        if provider_id:
            this_provider = Provider.objects.get(pk=provider_id)
            ctx['this_provider'] = this_provider
            ctx['categories'] = Category.objects.all()
            ctx['roles'] = this_provider.role.all()
            ctx['payments'] = Payment.objects.all()
            ctx['deliveries'] = Delivery.objects.all()
        return ctx
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to do anything? Calling `form.save()`, which happens in the superclass `form_valid`, will save all fields including many-to-many. You don't need to define your own `form_valid` at all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No need to rewrite the `form_valid`.

```
@method_decorator(currency_account_dec, name='dispatch')
class ProviderCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = ProviderForm
    template_name = 'provider_create.html'

    def post(self, request):
        provider_id = self.kwargs.get('provider_id',None)
        session_user = request.user
        form = ProviderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            rq = form.save(commit=False)
            if provider_id:
                rq.provider = Provider.objects.get(pk=provider_id)
            rq.user = self.request.user
            rq.save()
            rq.category = form.cleaned_data.get('category')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/providers/')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/providers/create/')
```

Comment: @DanielRoseman Can you show the right approach? I'm just learning ... I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can do `form.save()`

Comment: i.e. no need to override `form_valid()` since the default `form_valid` method calls `form.save()` already.